# Can I increase the size of the thread pool used by Corda nodes to handle RPC requests?

Tags: corda

The number of threads used by Corda nodes to handle RPC requests is defined in `RPCServerConfiguration`. Can the node owner configure this number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. It's been raised as a feature request here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-999.